# Flowfile attributes in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I wanted to monitor the JVM heap usage in Nifi. How can we increase the load of flow file attributes.I have tried the heap usage monitoring with respect to content size.

Comment: I don't clearly understand. Can you be a bit more elaborate on what you want? If you want to get the metrics like heap size, flowfile repo size, you can use `/system-diagnostics` endpoint which returns a whole lot of diagnostics information.

Comment: NiFi holds the majority of the FlowFile attribute data in the configured JVM heap memory space.Hence I would like to have a sample data flow to  monitor the utilization by keeping the heap space fixed and progressively increasing the flowfile count and then increasing the flowfile load

Answer (score 2):

The GenerateFlowFile processor can be used to generate whatever type of flow files you want.

Any user-defined attributes in the processor will become attributes on each flow file, and the content of the flow files can be controller with the Custom Text property.

The speed of flow files being produced can be controlled by the scheduling strategy of the processor. It defaults to 0 seconds which means it will run as fast as possible, so you will probably want to start out with something slower initially.